# I cannot connect to my sandbox

Tags: node, blockchain

I started a sandbox with : ./src/bin_node/tezos-sandboxed-node.sh 1 --connections 1

I tried to connect with tezos-client -A 127.0.0.1 -P 7089

I get the error :

- error: Unable to connect to the node: "TLS to non-TCP currently     unsupported: host=http://127.0.0.1 endp=(Unknown "name resolution failed")"

Comment: The port seems to be incorrect. The default port for the node "1" in the sandbox should be `18731`.

Answer (score 1):

The `src/bin_node/tezos-sandboxed-node.sh` script that launches a sandboxed node is meant to be used with the `src/bin_client/tezos-init-sandboxed-client.sh` one that sets some env variables and bash aliases. The tutorial documentation for these scripts is here: https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/sandbox.html.

Answer (score 0):

unless you are doing development on the Tezos platform, I suggest you have a look at this tool https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/teztool/-/tree/master to run a sandbox node.

In particular: https://gitlab.com/nomadic-labs/teztool/-/blob/master/docs/sandbox.md

These scripts are mean for development and to be used in the CI.

Together with this sandbox, you can use this snapcraft for the client : https://gitlab.com/abate/tezos-snapcraft/-/tree/master